# How can I automate displaying mxGraphModel in draw.io?

Tags: mxgraph, draw.io

I have prepared a mxGraphModel in my console app (that is written in Java) and I would like to automate one of the following:

- opening draw.io / diagrams.net displaying its content
- export it as an image to a file: png, svg, pdf, any type actually

The main goal is to visualise this graph anyhow.

Is there a way of doing this or something similar?

```
<mxGraphModel dx="1325" dy="753" grid="1" gridSize="10" guides="1" tooltips="1" connect="1" arrows="1" fold="1" page="1" pageScale="1" pageWidth="827" pageHeight="1169" math="0" shadow="0">
  <root>
    <mxCell id="0" />
    <mxCell id="1" parent="0" />
    <mxCell id="q9gYvhBhvbTBP0PCmc48-1" value="" style="rounded=0;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;" parent="1" vertex="1">
      <mxGeometry x="120" y="80" width="680" height="40" as="geometry" />
    </mxCell>
    <mxCell id="q9gYvhBhvbTBP0PCmc48-2" value="" style="ellipse;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;" parent="1" vertex="1">
      <mxGeometry x="120" y="160" width="40" height="40" as="geometry" />
    </mxCell>
    <mxCell id="q9gYvhBhvbTBP0PCmc48-3" value="" style="ellipse;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;" parent="1" vertex="1">
      <mxGeometry x="230" y="145" width="70" height="70" as="geometry" />
    </mxCell>
    <mxCell id="q9gYvhBhvbTBP0PCmc48-4" value="" style="ellipse;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;" parent="1" vertex="1">
      <mxGeometry x="450" y="170" width="20" height="20" as="geometry" />
    </mxCell>
    <mxCell id="q9gYvhBhvbTBP0PCmc48-5" value="" style="ellipse;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;" parent="1" vertex="1">
      <mxGeometry x="200" y="230" width="40" height="40" as="geometry" />
    </mxCell>
    <mxCell id="q9gYvhBhvbTBP0PCmc48-6" value="" style="ellipse;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;" parent="1" vertex="1">
      <mxGeometry x="310" y="215" width="70" height="70" as="geometry" />
    </mxCell>
    <mxCell id="q9gYvhBhvbTBP0PCmc48-7" value="" style="ellipse;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;fillColor=#d5e8d4;strokeColor=#82b366;" parent="1" vertex="1">
      <mxGeometry x="530" y="240" width="20" height="20" as="geometry" />
    </mxCell>
  </root>
</mxGraphModel>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could publish a viewer version following https://desk.draw.io/support/solutions/articles/16000051941-how-to-publicly-publish-a-copy-of-your-draw-io-diagram

You could use the CLI in the desktop version to automate conversions, https://j2r2b.github.io/2019/08/06/drawio-cli.html